# How to pass parameter to my custom filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, filter

How to pass parameter to my custom filters. I tried the following way but I don't know how to pass the parameters.

```
public class AuditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private PCBAuditEntities _entity = new PCBAuditEntities();

        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            //Stores the Request in an Accessible object
            HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
            string actionname = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            //Generate an audit
            Audit audit = new Audit()
                {

                    IpAddress = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? request.UserHostAddress,
                    UrlAccessed = request.RawUrl,
                    TimeAccessed = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    UserName = (request.IsAuthenticated) ? filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name : "Anonymous",
                    Actionname = actionname,
                    EntityName ="" ,//what entity i changed?
                    FieldName = "",// How to find the FieldName?
                    Operations = "",// what operatins client did?
                    NewValue = "",// what is the new value?
                    Oldvalue = "",// what is the old value?

                };
            _entity.Audits.Add(audit);
            _entity.SaveChanges();

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }



    }

    [Audit(IsRequired = true)]
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }
```

In above code `IsRequired` only we asigned the true or false so I easyly sent the parameters whether I need send the `EntityName`, `FieldName`, `NewValue`, `Oldvalue`

How can I send the value from controller ?

Comment: `How can i send the above values from controller?` - you subscribed to the `OnActionExecuting` event which executes **BEFORE** the controller action has ran. So talking about sending such values from the controller to the action filter is kinda meaningless. It's like trying to drive your car before you actually bought it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov sorry i dont know about coustom filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all probably you want to override OnActionExecuted event.

To pass parameter you have to create constructor with parameter:

```
private paramType param;

public AuditAttribute(paramType param)
{
     this.param = param;
}
```

Comment: Ok.. How to write controller